# Glossaries Acronyms generate overfull hbox: how do to line wrap?

Tags: line-breaking, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package with the acronym option:

```
\usepackage[acronym,style=long3col]{glossaries}
```

For some reason the acronyms on first use will not line wrap, e.g.,

```
\newacronym{VHDL}{VHDL}{Very High Speed Integrated Circuit (VHSIC) Hardware Description Language}
```

I have tried using hyphenation but I can't seem to get LaTeX to detect the spaces in the acronyms and wrap the acronym around the next line.

How can I get latex to wrap the text to the next line for long ancronyms when first used or after `\glsreset{}` is used?

Comment: I guess you’re compiling your document with `latex` and the `dvips` output driver (which doesn’t support breaking links across lines). Try `latex` in conjunction with the `dvipdfmx` output driver or `pdflatex` in conjunction with the `pdftex` output driver.

Comment: my compilation command is: latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %.aux|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|dvips -o %.ps %.dvi|ps2pdf %.ps|evince %.pdf (from texmaker) I need to do ps first as I am using epsfig and vaucanson-g

Comment: OK, then I guessed right. P.S.: The `epsfig` package is outdated.

Comment: any solution then?

Comment: I have tried to use graphicx instead and then use pdflatex, but even after including pst-pdf to deal with pspictures I am still not able to compile. This is because I am using vaucanson-g and it uses vcpicture (i think part of pstricks-add) and this then causes an issue

Comment: Actually, the [`breakurl`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/breakurl/breakurl.pdf) package facilitates breaking links across lines when the `dvips` output driver is used. But unfortunately, it only supports `\url` links.

Comment: I have no problem with this acronym. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: This question is not localized, at all, and should be reopened.  This is a general problem I encounter fairly often.